# Twilio masked phone numbers (1 number for multiple calls?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio, ruby-on-rails-5

is it possible to use 1 masked phone number for different calls between different users? I'm building a webapplication and up till now the maximum amount of calls at the same moment is 10. So my idea was to have like 15 different masked number that can be used for all these different calls?

Another question: can the masked number be customized with text or emoji's?

P.S.: I'm looking for someone who can help me with implementing this feature. So if you are interested, feel free to contact me ;-).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio numbers can be used to make many calls at the same time. If all your users have different numbers, then you can call any of them at the same time from one Twilio number.

If you are setting up a longer term connection between two users on which they communicate with each other via the masked number, then you need as many numbers as the user with the maximum number of concurrent relationships has. [This article is about this situation for SMS messages, but the principle is the same for making phone calls too](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134067-How-users-can-send-text-messages-to-each-other-over-Twilio).

If you do need to set up these relationships, check out [Twilio Proxy](https://www.twilio.com/proxy) and get in touch if you would like to try it out.

Comment: Thanks! It's a pretty sweet API. I'm now learning ruby to be able to build cool stuff with all these great resources :-)

Comment: That's awesome to hear! I'll be about here if you need any more help or just give me a shout elsewhere (contact details on my profile page) if I can help more.